# jqplot not triggering"jqplotDataClick" event within backbone.js view

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jqplot

I have a jqplot chart as part of a Backbone.js view. The chart and it's data all load fine, but mouse highlighting and click on the chart don't seem to be registered.
It works fine in the jqplot examples. It is only when I add it to my Backbone.js framework that it stops working.

I have tried using "jqplotDataHighlight" and "jqplotClick" and neither of them trigger an event, **however
"jqplotDataUnhighlight" works fine**. I can't figure out why one works and the other don't.

```
//part of Backbone.js View....
        var l2 = [11, 9, 5, 12, 14];    
        var l3 = [4, 8, 5, 3, 6];    
        var l4 = [12, 6, 13, 11, 2]; 

        //this event never triggers
        this.$('#plot3').bind('jqplotDataHighlight',         
           function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) { 
               alert('highlight');           
               $('#info1b').html('series: '+seriesIndex+', point: '+pointIndex+', data: '+data);        
           }); 

           //unhighlight event work just as expected  
        this.$('#plot3').bind('jqplotDataUnhighlight',         
               function (ev) {
                    alert("this worked: unhighlight")            
                    $('#info1b').html('Nothing');        
        });

        //chart load fine, showing all data             
        this.$('#plot3').jqplot([l2, l3, l4],{       
              stackSeries: true,       
              showMarker: false,       
              seriesDefaults: {           
                  fill: true       
              },       
              axes: {           
                 xaxis: {               
                      renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,               
                      ticks: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thr", "Fri"]           
                 }       
              }    
          });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I will answer my own question after hours of debugging. Which will hopefully help some poor fool who makes mistakes like I do.

During my testing I had added in all of the jqplot pluggins and I finally found out the the mobile pluggin overrides some of the main jqplot event handlers like onClich which was causing the problems. I remove the mobile pluggin and everything worked like a charm.

Comment: YOU ARE THE MAN.  Struggling with this jqplot problem for a while